# linq group by timespan

Tags: c#, .net, linq, entity-framework

How is it possible to group by a timespan? What I'm trying to do is get the total minutes, and perform a get timespan from minutes function.

Ultimately I'm trying to get the average time spent on a particular account in one month.
I'm also looking at trying to find the total time spent on a particular account too.

I feel like I'm close but everything I've tried in the select statement doesn't seem to work.

```
period = new DateTime(2013,1,1);
endPeriod = new DateTime(2013,1,1).AddMonths(1).AddDays(-1);
account.AccountNumber = 1455;

var q = from logs in db.logs
where logs.AccountNumber == account.AccountNumber
where logs.StartDateTime > period && logs.StartDateTime < endPeriod
let time = new TimeSpan(logs.ElapsedHours, logs.ElapsedMinutes, 0).TotalMinutes
group logs by time into g
select new {
AvgTime = g.Average(g.Key)

}
```

This query is currently returning 5 rows. It should only be returning 1. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Any suggestions?

Mike

Comment: Do you have some sample data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I ended up with:

```
var result = (from logs in db.logs
         where logs.AccountNumber == 1450
         where logs.StartDateTime > new DateTime(2013,1,1) && logs.StartDateTime < new DateTime(2013,1,31)
         group logs by logs.AccountNumber into g
         select new {
             AvgTime = (g.Sum(h=>h.ElapsedHours) * 60) + g.Sum(h=>h.ElapsedMinutes) / g.Count(),
             TotalTime = (g.Sum(h=>h.ElapsedHours) * 60) + g.Sum(h=>h.ElapsedMinutes)
         }).ToList()
         .Select(x=> new {
            AvgTime = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(x.AvgTime),
            TotalTime = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(x.TotalTime)
         });
```

Answer (score 0):

Your query is a bit confusing - you're grouping by a value (timespan) but then apparently trying to compute an average of the *key* values, rather than an average of the items within each group. If that is truly the case try this:

```
period = new DateTime(2013,1,1);
endPeriod = new DateTime(2013,1,1).AddMonths(1).AddDays(-1);
account.AccountNumber = 1455;

var q = from logs in db.logs
where logs.AccountNumber == account.AccountNumber
&& logs.StartDateTime > period && logs.StartDateTime < endPeriod
let time = new TimeSpan(logs.ElapsedHours, logs.ElapsedMinutes, 0).TotalMinutes
group logs by time into g
select new {
Time = g.Key
}

var averageTime = q.Average(i => i.Time);
```

`g.Key` will only give you one value for each group, which is why you are seeing 5 records (I'm assuming that your data will produce 5 groups).